# How do I locate the exact location where this error is occurring 404 page not found

Tags: posts, jquery, 404-error

I recently installed a wordpress theme and lots of plugins. This error appears on blog post after refreshing page for second time anywhere in between the post content. Here's the link to my site:

http://designer-grid.com/best-wordpress-plugins-for-2012-must-have/

> Not Found The requested URL /jquery-1.6.3.min.js was not found on this
>   server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
>   mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
>   mod_fcgid/2.3.6 Server at www.jquerys.org Port 80

Comment: I see no errors whatsoever. Yes, I did refresh the page many times. No errors.

Comment: I tried in seperate browsers and its still showing me error message. You can have a look at the screenshot. http://i.imgur.com/5lRlR.jpg  Position of error message varies with every page refresh.

Comment: Check this out — http://i.imgur.com/foLQL.png — like I said, it's showing up fine here.

Comment: Can't see the error either...

Comment: that intriguing!!

Comment: I can only think of some browser add-on interference... Have you tried with different browsers? . . . Take a look at this [Google search](http://www.google.es/search?hl=en&client=safari&biw=480&bih=268&q=404+%22Server+at+www.jquerys.org+Port+80%22&oq=404+%22Server+at+www.jquerys.org+Port+80%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...18718.21713.0.22766.2.2.0.0.0.0.2921.3293.3-1j9-1.2.0...0.0...1ac.J1lpwm_NN-c&mvs=0), 35500 results!

Comment: Got the cause of the error!! The path to jquery library which was hosted on another server was dead. So I removed that link from functions.php file and the problem has now been resolved.